# Design with async/await - should everything be async?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Assume I have an interface method implemented as

```
public void DoSomething(User user) 
{
    if (user.Gold > 1000) ChatManager.Send(user, "You are rich: " + user.Gold);
}
```

After some time I realize that I want to change it:

```
public async Task DoSomething(User user) 
{
    if (user.Gold > 1000) ChatManager.Send(user, "You are rich: " + user.Gold);
    if (!user.HasReward)
    {
         using(var dbConnection = await DbPool.OpenConnectionAsync())
         {
             await dbConnection.Update(user, u => 
                        {
                            u.HasReward = true;
                            u.Gold += 1000;
                        });
         }
    }
}
```

I'm changing the method signature in the interface. But the calling methods were synchronous and I have to make not only them async but also the whole call tree async.

Example:

```
void A()
{
    _peer.SendResponse("Ping: " + _x.B());
}

double X.B()
{
    return _someCollection.Where(item => y.C(item)).Average();
}


bool Y.C(int item)
{
   // ...
   _z.DoSomething();
   return _state.IsCorrect;
}
```

should be changed to

```
async void AAsync()
{
    _peer.SendResponse("Ping: " + await _x.BAsync());
}

async Task<double> X.BAsync()
{
    // await thing breaks LINQ!
    var els = new List<int>();
    foreach (var el in _someCollection)
    {
        if (await y.CAsync(item)) els.Add(el);
    }
    return _els.Average();
}


async Task<bool> Y.CAsync(int item)
{
   // ...
   await _z.DoSomething();
   return _state.IsCorrect;
}
```

The affected call tree may be very big (many systems and interfaces) so this change is hard to do.

Also when the first `A` method is called from interface method like `IDisposable.Dispose` - I can't make it async.

Another example: imagine that multiple calls to `A` were stored as delegates. Previously they were just called with `_combinedDelegate.Invoke()` but now I should go through `GetInvocationList()` and `await` on each item.

Oh, and consider also replacing property getter with async method.

I can't use `Task.Wait()` or `.Result` because:

1. It's wasting `ThreadPool` threads in server app
2. It leads to deadlocks: if all `ThreadPool` threads are `Wait`ing there are no threads to complete any task.

So the question is: should I make absolutely all my methods initially `async` even if I'm not planning to call anything async inside? Won't it hurt performance? Or how to design things to avoid such hard refactorings?

Comment: You don't *have* to make the calling methods async - they can just do the call to the async method as `var result = SomeAsyncMethod().Result`. In this way, you can break the "async chain" until you are ready to refactor further up the call tree.

Comment: *Won't it hurt performance?* Probably not in adverse ways. *How to design things to avoid such hard refactorings?* Asynchrony carries a price -- on one hand you can lazy-defer everything, but on the other, for non-trivial cases, it requires upstream code to support it (e.g. if your form validator engine doesn't support asynchrony, you're basically SOL and have to block on it).

Comment: Infecting the call tree is the eternal torment of async codebases.

Comment: @Rb As a side note: You should always use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of .Result - gives you the right exception instead of one wrapped in an aggregate exception.

Comment: @Voo I did not know that! The number of times I've written the same boilerplate code to unwrap exceptions is actually embarrassing now...! Thanks :-)

Comment: This is the worst part of Javascript, by far, IMO.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> should I make absolutely all my methods initially async even if I'm not planning to call anything async inside?

This design problem with `async` is essentially the same as the problem with `IDisposable`. That is, interfaces *have* to predict their implementations. And this is going to be messy, no matter what you do.

In my experience, it's usually rather straightforward to consider a method/interface/class and predict whether it will use I/O or not. If it requires I/O, then it should probably be made task-returning. Sometimes (but not always), it's possible to structure your code so that I/O is done in its own section of the code, leaving business objects and logic strictly synchronous. The Redux pattern in the JavaScript world is a good example of this.

But bottom line, sometimes you make the wrong call and have to refactor. I think this is a far better approach than just making *every* method asynchronous. Do you make *every* interface inherit from `IDisposable` and use `using` everywhere? Nah, you only add it when necessary; and you should take the same approach with `async`.

Comment: `IDisposable` is a much easier case: 1. often `IDisposable` objects are used only inside methods (not stored as a field anywhere) so only direct callers are affected. 2. Calling `Dispose` is often optional, you can just leave things for finalizer.; 
btw consider adding an async call to an existing `IDisposable.Dispose` method.

Comment: *I mean async call from `Dispose`

Comment: Are there any C# examples of "structure your code so that I/O is done in its own section of the code, leaving business objects and logic strictly synchronous"?

Comment: @Vlad: I'm not aware of anything specific.

Comment: Not only IO requires await. Also switching between synchronization contexts requires await. I can't predict whether there will be interactions between users (each runs in its own sync context).

Comment: I mean Actor interactions in Actor-based concurrency.

Comment: @Vlad: Actors typically use a fire-and-forget messaging model. But if you're (asynchronously) waiting for a response, then yes, you would need `await`.

Comment: So according to that I can't predict whether some method will need to interact with another Actor method (may be deeply in call tree) I have to use async almost everywhere.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, again, *if* your actors wait for other actors to respond before finishing their current message.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I make absolutely all my methods initially async even if I'm not planning to call anything async inside?

No, you should not. Making everything `async` hurts reading, writing and understanding your code, even if only a little. It could also hurt the performance of your code, especially if you really made every single method (does that include properties?) `async`.

> How to design things to avoid such hard refactorings?

To some degree, such refactorings might be necessary.

But you can avoid a lot of the pain by structuring your code correctly using the single responsibility principle. A method that checks whether state is correct should definitely not send chat messages. This way, changing one method to `async` shouldn't affect too much code.